after k-means clustering, how to do proportion?
I have 5 columns (k=5) of data which are gender, education, age, years of marriage and amount spent and need to do k-means clustering.
After doing k-means clustering, I am require to determine the number of samples and the calculate the number of 0 and 1 (under another column named default) in each cluster.
K = 5
random_seed = 1

model = KMeans(n_clusters=K, random_state=random_seed)

model.fit(data_norm1)

df1_norm = pd.DataFrame(data_norm1, columns=df_1.columns)

cluster_labels = model.labels_
df1_norm['Cluster1'] = cluster_labels

df1_norm

cluster_counts = df1_norm.groupby('Cluster1').size()
cluster_counts

proportion_0 = df1_norm.groupby('Cluster1')['default'].mean()

I managed to calculate the number of sample but unable to group into 0 and 1 at each cluster.
At the earlier part of the code (before clustering), I have group the full set of data into 0 and 1.
one_default = df[df['default'] == 1]
zero_default = df[df['default'] == 0]

Error message is "KeyError: 'Column not found: DEFAULT"

Here is an approach with a sample dataframe. Adapt it to your own data:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = {
    'gender': np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], size=100),
    'education': np.random.choice(['High School', 'Bachelors', 'Masters', 'PhD'], size=100),
    'age': np.random.randint(20, 70, size=100),
    'years_of_marriage': np.random.randint(0, 50, size=100),
    'amount_spent': np.random.randint(100, 10000, size=100),
    'default': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['gender'] = df['gender'].map({'Male': 0, 'Female': 1})
df['education'] = df['education'].map({'High School': 0, 'Bachelors': 1, 'Masters': 2, 'PhD': 3})

scaler = StandardScaler()
data_norm = scaler.fit_transform(df.drop(columns='default'))

K = 5
random_seed = 1
model = KMeans(n_clusters=K, random_state=random_seed)
model.fit(data_norm)

df_norm = pd.DataFrame(data_norm, columns=df.drop(columns='default').columns)
df_norm['Cluster'] = model.labels_
df_norm['default'] = df['default'].values

cluster_counts = df_norm.groupby('Cluster').size()

default_counts = df_norm.groupby(['Cluster', 'default']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)


print(cluster_counts)
print(default_counts)

which returns
Cluster
0    27
1    22
2    12
3    17
4    22
dtype: int64
default   0   1
Cluster        
0        11  16
1        15   7
2         8   4
3         6  11
4        14   8

